# Reversing a List of ints

Tags: c#

I have the following code.  I have a listA of integers and created another listB that will take the integers from listA in a reverse order.  However, after I compile I get the "ArgumentOutOfRangeException".  I don't understand why I am getting this as I believe my indexing looks ok.

```
        List<int> listNum = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        listNum.Add(7);

        List<int> reverseList = new List<int>();

        int k = 0;
        int ListLength = listNum.Count-1;

        for (int i = ListLength; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            reverseList[k] = listNum[i];
            k++;
        }
```

Comment: `reverseList` has zero items in it. Zero. None. *Any* index into `reverseList` is out of range.

Comment: Before asking, you have plenty of room for debugging yourself here. For instance, put a print statement in your for loop that logs `k` and `i` as well as `reverseList.Count` and `listNum.Count`, and you should be able to discover the problem 100% on your own.

Comment: You can use `listNum.Reverse()`. If you want to keep the order of your original list, just copy the list: `List<int> reverseList = listNum.ToList()` and reverse it: `reverseList.Reverse()`

Comment: Replace `reverseList[k] = listNum[i];` with `reverseList.Add(listNum[i])`  and look up how arrays and lists work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is direct method [Enumerable.Reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497(v=vs.110).aspx), you can do as below

```
listNum .Reverse()
```

---

for your code do like this

```
  for (int i = ListLength -1; i >= 0; i--)
     reverseList.Add( listNum[i]);
```

just for the information it's `List` it's not array

Comment: What Pranay means with his final comment is that a `List` and an `array` are different things. A list initially has no elements in it; unlike an array of a fixed size, there is nothing at position 3 that you can access with myList[3]. If your array was declared with `int[] myArray = new int[5]` there WOULD be a `myArray[3]`. If you say `List myList = new List(5)` that merely creates a list that has an initial capacity for 5 items (it can grow), but it doesnt have 5 items; it has 0 items. Call `Add()` five times and it will then have 5 items, and won't crash if you do `myList[3]`

Comment: @CaiusJard - gr8 i think op need to read C# book and have to read list vs array section ...:)

Answer (score 1):

This is because reverseList has 0 elements.
To fix this you could do below in for loop 
`reverseList[k].Add(listNum[i]);`

or simple use linq

`reverseList  = listNum.Reverse();`